# Will a preflight request be triggered if the request is same-origin but does not follow the header guidelines?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, cors

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests

> The following is an example of a request that will be preflighted:
>
> ```
> const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
> xhr.open('POST', 'https://bar.other/resources/post-here/');  
> xhr.setRequestHeader('X-PINGOTHER', 'pingpong');  
> xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');  
> xhr.onreadystatechange = handler;
> xhr.send('<person><name>Arun</name></person>');
> ```
>
> The example above creates an XML body to send with the `POST` request.
> Also, a non-standard HTTP `X-PINGOTHER` request header is set. Such
> headers are not part of HTTP/1.1, but are generally useful to web
> applications. Since the request uses a `Content-Type` of
> `application/xml`, and since a custom header is set, this request is
> preflighted.

Will a preflight request be triggered if the request is same-origin but does not follow the header guidelines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, preflight requests are only done for cross-site requests. If you look at the beginning of the MDN article there is an image that explicitly says "Same origin-requets (always allowed)" as an example.

*The below image isn't very visible if running SO in dark mode, if so, check the image in the article on the url below.*

[image: Sample image from article]

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS